# How do I force Amazon EC2 instance to use my Elastic IP when I FTP out to a remote server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ftp, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to FTP out to a remote server from by EC2 instance, but upon login, if I send any FTP commands, the remote server disconnects.  Through my testing, it seems that the remote FTP server is getting the private IP Address from my EC2 instance instead of the public Elastic IP assigned to it.  Is there a way to "force" my instance to send the public IP when initiating the connection?

Comment: Is the FTP server on AWS ?

Comment: To my knowledge, no.  Also, I might add that my instance is EC2 Classic.  The problem that I have run into is that I can "connect" to the remote FTP server and login as well as traverse the available directories, but if I 'ls' or try to 'get' a file I know exists (I can connect from my laptop), I get the following message: 421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection.

Comment: You need to use passive mode. FTP is an old protocal and doesnt traverse NAT all that well.